# can you use the ruby percent notation for strings with interpolation?

Tags: ruby, string, interpolation

I'm using template strings in ruby. Example:

```
foo = "bar"
"let's go to the #{foo}" #=> let's go to the bar
```

I've got a lot of strings with special characters in them, and stumbled upon the %q delimiter trick, which has been super useful.

```
%q["I don't respect them", he said] #=> "\"I don't respect them\", he said"
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work with interpolation.

```
catchphrase = 'wubba lubba dub dub'
%[My new catchphrase is "#{catchphrase}"] #=> "My new catchphrase is \"\#{catchphrase}\""
```

Any thoughts on how to get interpolation and % notation to play nicely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `%Q` instead of `%q`. For instance:

```
catchphrase = 'wubba lubba dub dub'
%Q[My new catchphrase is "#{catchphrase}"] #=> "My new catchphrase is \"wubba lubba dub dub\""
```

Comment: To explain a bit more why this works, %q is the same as using 'string', whereas %Q is the same as using "string". In ruby, using 'string' does not allow for interpolation, therefore %q would also not allow it.